# Get my calculated Max row for sql complex query

Tags: sql

I have a table, and I want to get for each key the maximum row.
what is the maximum row?
for key 1: biggest A column: if there are few A columns, then take the biggest B column, if there are few, take the biggest C column. (the biggest one is the second row)

```
Key,  A, B, C
1,    1, 2, 1
1,    2, 1, 3
1,    1, 1, 1
1,    2, 1, 2
2,    2, 1, 2
2,    2, 2, 3
2,    1, 2, 2
2,    1, 2, 1
```

I want the result be:

```
Key,  A, B, C
1,    2, 1, 3
2,    2, 2, 3
```

any idea how can I do it?

Comment: Something like `select Key, Max(A), Max(B), Max(C) from Table group by Key`.

Comment: tried it and it returns all rows...

Comment: ? what database is this?

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE YourTableName (
    Keys INT,
    A INT,
    B INT,
    C INT
)

INSERT INTO YourTableName (Keys, A, B, C)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 2, 1),
    (1, 2, 1, 3),
    (1, 1, 1, 1),
    (1, 2, 1, 2),
    (2, 2, 1, 2),
    (2, 2, 2, 3),
    (2, 1, 2, 2),
    (2, 1, 2, 1)
```

```
8 rows affected
```

```
WITH RankedRows AS (
    SELECT 
        Keys, 
        A, 
        B, 
        C,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Keys ORDER BY A DESC, B DESC, C DESC) AS rn
    FROM 
        YourTableName
)
SELECT 
    Keys, 
    A, 
    B, 
    C
FROM 
    RankedRows
WHERE 
    rn = 1;
```

| Keys | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NKbMO997)